# What tools respect `.distignore`?

Tags: wp-cli

You can create a plugin using the `wp scaffold plugin PLUGINNAME` command. It creates a bunch of files, including `.distignore`, `.editorconfig`, `.gitignore`, `.travis.yml`.

Here is the contents of `.distignore`:

```
# A set of files you probably don't want in your WordPress.org distribution
.distignore
.editorconfig
.git
.gitignore
.gitlab-ci.yml
.travis.yml
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
behat.yml
bin
circle.yml
composer.json
composer.lock
Gruntfile.js
package.json
package-lock.json
phpunit.xml
phpunit.xml.dist
multisite.xml
multisite.xml.dist
phpcs.xml
phpcs.xml.dist
README.md
wp-cli.local.yml
yarn.lock
tests
vendor
node_modules
*.sql
*.tar.gz
*.zip
```

My question is: what tools recognise `.distignore`? Are they just wp-cli commands that recognise it? Do some online hosts like WP Engine recognise it?

Comment: Does [this topic](https://github.com/stephenharris/grunt-wp-deploy/issues/36) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is file for WP CLI. the command [`dist-archive`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/dist-archive/):

```
wp dist-archive .
```

Note that you need to install both WP CLI and this plugin:

```
wp package install wp-cli/dist-archive-command
```

Comment: This answer was rolled into a video on YouTube. For SEO money? I don't know. Anyway, it isn't my video, but it was so odd, I thought I'd make you aware. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pYLj5i6sjs

Comment: @jlbang That's interesting. [Everything on Stack Exchange is licensed under CC BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). So that means my question and answer can be reused in a video, as long as the video is licensed under CC BY-SA too. The video is licensed under CC BY, so it didn't quite abide by the requirements of the license.